# nginx.conf file for windows not working for plex

Tags: nginx, nat, plex

I have the following nginx.conf file on my windows server

```
    #user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        auth_basic on;
        auth_basic_user_file C:/nginx-1.13.5/nginx-1.13.5/conf/htpassword;

        location /sonarr {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8989;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }

        location /radarr {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7878;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }

        location /sabnzbd {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }

    location /plex {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:32400;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header Host $server_addr;
            proxy_set_header Referer $server_addr;
            proxy_set_header Origin $server_addr; 

            gzip on;
            gzip_vary on;
            gzip_min_length 1000;
            gzip_proxied any;
            gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml application/xml text/javascript application/x-javascript image/svg+xml;
            gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";

            client_max_body_size 100M;

            proxy_set_header X-Plex-Client-Identifier $http_x_plex_client_identifier;
            proxy_set_header X-Plex-Device $http_x_plex_device;
            proxy_set_header X-Plex-Device-Name $http_x_plex_device_name;
            proxy_set_header X-Plex-Platform $http_x_plex_platform;
            proxy_set_header X-Plex-Platform-Version $http_x_plex_platform_version;
            proxy_set_header X-Plex-Product $http_x_plex_product;
            proxy_set_header X-Plex-Token $http_x_plex_token;
            proxy_set_header X-Plex-Version $http_x_plex_version;
            proxy_set_header X-Plex-Nocache $http_x_plex_nocache;
            proxy_set_header X-Plex-Provides $http_x_plex_provides;
            proxy_set_header X-Plex-Device-Vendor $http_x_plex_device_vendor;
            proxy_set_header X-Plex-Model $http_x_plex_model;

            # Web Sockets
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_buffering off;
    }
    }
}
```

I have ngrok running on port 80 so I can access my server from outside my network and every single endpoint works with the exception of the /plex address. When I go to http://.ngrok.io/plex I get "401 Unauthorized" after being asked to enter my basic auth username and password. Does anyone have any idea what is amiss from my nginx.conf?

Or any other ideas for how I get get around Carrier Grade NAT to access my server from outside my network? So far I requested help from my ISP and I haven't heard back which makes me feel like they are just brushing me off so I need to try and find a long term solution on my own.